# Find questions where any of the tags are in the title or body?

Tags: support, tags, data-explorer, sql

I would like to find posts where any of the tags are present in the title or body of the question, e.g. **Python** and **C#** are the tags and title is **Fix my Python Problem?**

```
SELECT TOP 10

Posts.Id,
Posts.Title,
Posts.Body,
Posts.Tags

From Posts

--where any of the tags is in the title or body
;
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks for contributing! My final output is below. I created fields for showing which word is where.

```
SELECT TOP 10
p.Id, 
p.Tags,
t.TagName,
CASE
  WHEN p.Title LIKE '%' + t.TagName + '%' THEN 'TITLE'
  WHEN p.Body LIKE '%' + t.TagName + '%' THEN 'BODY'
  ELSE NULL
END AS [Tag Match],
p.Title,
p.Body,
p.CreationDate,
p.Score

FROM Posts AS p

INNER JOIN PostTags AS pt
  ON p.Id = pt.PostId
  
INNER JOIN Tags AS t
  ON t.Id = pt.TagId
  
WHERE (p.Title LIKE '%' + t.TagName + '%'
       OR p.Body LIKE '%' + t.TagName + '%')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to JOIN with the PostTags and Tags tables, e.g. like [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1314234/questions-with-any-of-the-tags-in-the-title-or-body):

```
SELECT TOP 10 p.Id AS [Post Link], p.Tags
  FROM Posts AS p
  INNER JOIN PostTags AS pt
    ON p.Id = pt.PostId
  INNER JOIN Tags AS t
    ON t.Id = pt.TagId
  WHERE ' ' + p.Title + ' ' LIKE ' %' + t.TagName + ' %'
     OR ' ' + p.Body + ' ' LIKE ' %' + t.TagName + ' %'
```

I'm not sure that produces the results you want; you might want to filter on specific tags. But it gives you an idea of what is possible.

Comment: Super job, thanks. Is there any way to return the string matched?

Comment: You're welcome! I guess you can just add `t.TagName` to the `SELECT` part?

Comment: Added in my update above. I didn't opt for spaces around the words as in your solution.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't fancy joining over 2 tables as shown in [the answer by Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/355748/158100) you can [String_Split](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) the `Tags` field (which will hold `<c#><python>` in your example) and then juggle a bit with the value you get. The tag value will have a > at the end and with a Left function we strip that off.

Notice that I use a collation to cater for differences in upper and lower case characters. I also prefer several LIKE statements to handle the cases where a tag might be at the start or at the end. That prevents that the Query Engine needs to create new strings for each row in the Posts table.

Here is that [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1314235)

```
SELECT TOP 10

Posts.Id,
Posts.Title,
Posts.Body,
Posts.Tags

From Posts
cross apply string_split(Tags,'<')

where posttypeid = 1 -- Questions
and len(value) > 0 -- skip empty
and ( -- cater for tags at the start of the title, in the middle or at the end
   title like concat('% ', left(value,len(value)-1), ' %') collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI -- anywhere
or title like concat(left(value,len(value)-1), ' %') collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI -- start of title
or title like concat('% ', left(value,len(value)-1)) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI -- end of title
)
```

I left out the clause for the body. I leave that as an exercise for the reader. Keep in mind there that the `Body` contains the rendered html. For tags at the start or end of a sentence/paragraph needs special handling.

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the very useful [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the awesome [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `LIKE` operator and the `%` wildcard. For [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) it would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE (title LIKE '%C#%') OR (body LIKE '%C#%');
```

To search for another tag, simply enter the name of that tag within the percent signs.

If you need to search for more than one tag at a time, you can build a loop.